# Remove Filename From Filepath c++

Tags: c++

So I have this code that removes the filename from the filepath, but how do I do the opposite i.e. remove everything except the filename?

```cpp
sd::string filename = "C:\\Testdir\\file.exe";
const size_t last_slash_idx = filepath_modify.rfind('\\');
if (std::string::npos != last_slash_idx) {
    filepath_modify = filepath_modify.substr(0, last_slash_idx);
};
```

So if I have this filepath `"C:\\Testdir\\file.exe"` it will become `"file.exe"`.

How would I get everything *except* the filename?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<filesystem>` header:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
std::filesystem::path filepath{"C:\\Testdir\\file.exe"};
std::string filename = filepath.filename();
//"file.exe"
std::string folderpath = filepath.parent_path();
//"C:\\Testdir\\"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```cpp
std::string filepath = "C:\\Testdir\\file.exe";
const size_t last_slash_idx = filepath.rfind('\\', filepath_modify.length());
if (std::string::npos != last_slash_idx) {
    filepath =filepath.substr(last_slash_idx + 1, filepath.length() - last_slash_idx);
};
```

Comment: I'd recommend using modern C++ approaches, like using the `std::filesystem::path`.